# Maven Snapshots & Project aggregation.

Tags: maven

I have 2 maven modules that are both snapshot builds since they are in active development. 
For sake of discussion, the 2 modules are common, & web. Web depends on common. 
I am using project aggregation to define the individual modules. 
If i execute a goal, lets say mvn test on the parent pom.xml that contains the modules common & web the test goal on both the modules run as expected. 
If I run test on just the web module, it is unable to find the dependency for common. In other words, it is unable to find the common snapshot jar.Since its a snapshot, it does not get deployed to a repo so that makes sense. 
My question is, when I run the parent pom (project aggregation) how does it find that dependency? Where does that common module artifact get deployed to so the web module can get to it and resolve its dependency.

Comment: If you run it locally you only have to install one artifact to use it from another one. Just use the Snapshot in your dependencies.

Comment: In the web.pom, I have the following **dependency** defined`<dependency>
   <artifactId>common</artifactId>
   <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Why don't you try to use 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be able to run it everywhere you can deploy your snapshot libs into a local repository:
in your case deploy common into web with this command:

mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///your/web-project/root/dir -Dfile=your-common.jar -DgroupId= -DartifactId= -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=x.x-SNAPSHOT

this will generate a local repo dir structure with your jar into it. then modify your web's pom.xml with:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by Franz Ebner in his comment, first run:

```
# for the core pom:
mvn install
```

which puts the core artifact into your local machine maven 2 repo,
from where it can be fetched when you build/test/whatever the web artifact.